# Firebase Cloud Functions hosting, 'once' callback works in cloud functions but not in hosting site

Tags: javascript, firebase, https, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase Cloud Functions to read data with an HTTP trigger, and it is working perfectly fine in the cloudfunctions.net URL that is provided by default.

Now, for personal purposes I am using Firebase Hosting. I am trying to get a value when a child in the database is changed, which works in the Function URL but when accessed in the hosting URL it only works once, then it always displays the same thing as it did in the first time. It doesn't wait to load new changes in the database.

This is the code I am using:

```
exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
  res.set('Vary', 'Accept-Encoding, X-My-Custom-Header');
  var counter  = admin.database().ref('/Rac');
  counter.once('child_changed', (snapshot) =>{
  res.send(snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: You're setting cache headers on your response: `res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');`. This means that the response you send will be cached (by the CDN and possibly your browser) for as long as you indicate (5 or 10 minutes). If you don't want the response cached, don't set cache headers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting cache headers on your response:

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
```

This means that the response you send will be cached (by the CDN and possibly your browser) for as long as you indicate (5 or 10 minutes).

If you don't want the response cached, don't set cache headers.